# Plotting NSolve solution by ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I am trying to plot the values of the solution to NSolve: {τ4, τ3, τ2, τ1} by connected lines, while each line shows these 4 values for a specific value of the parameter (a)? But in the following codes, it seems that NSolve doesn't recognize the values of the parameter (a), specified by:

```
set = a -> # & /@ Range[0, 3, 0.5];
```

In addition, for the labels, is there a way to show just the first one (a=0) and the sixth one (a=0.5) on the curves, instead of all labels, and also on the left hand side of the curves instead of the right-hand side?

```
gamma4 = .4;
gamma3 = .284;
gamma2 = .265;
gamma1 = .484;
z3 = 10000;
z2 = 32000;
z1 = 75000;
zbar4 = 4800;
zbar3 = 20050;
zbar2 = 46200;
zbar1 = 138100;
h4 = .301;
h3 = .404;
h2 = .25;
h1 = .045;
p1 = 3.89;
p2 = 4.92;
p3 = 5.22;
p4 = 5.39;
g1 = 0;
g2 = 0.44;
g3 = 0.88;
g4 = 1.76;




eq1 = (\[Tau]1/(1 - \[Tau]1)) - ((1 - 
       g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) (zbar1 - 
        z1)/((1 - ((g1 a p1/\[Tau]1) + g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + 
            g4 a p4)) zbar1 gamma1));
Print["0=", eq1];

eq2 = (\[Tau]2/(1 - \[Tau]2)) - (((1 - 
          g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 (zbar2 - z2) + (1 - 
          g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h1 (z1 - 
          z2))/((1 - (g1 a p1 + (g2 a p2/\[Tau]2) + g3 a p3 + 
           g4 a p4)) (zbar2 h2 gamma2)));
Print["0=", eq2];

eq3 = (\[Tau]3/(1 - \[Tau]3)) - (((1 - 
          g3 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + g4 a p4)) h3 (zbar3 - 
          z3) + ((1 - g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 + (1 - 
             g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h1) (z2 - 
          z3))/((1 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + (g3 a p3/\[Tau]3) + 
           g4 a p4)) zbar3 h3 gamma3));
Print["0=", eq3];

eq4 = (\[Tau]4/(1 - \[Tau]4)) - (((1 - 
          g4 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + 
            g3 a p3)) h4 (zbar4) + ((1 - 
             g3 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + g4 a p4)) h3 + (1 - 
             g2 - (g1 a p1 + g3 a p3 + g4 a p4)) h2 + (1 - 
             g1 - (g2 a p2 + g3 a p3 + 
               g4 a p4)) h1) z3)/((1 - (g1 a p1 + g2 a p2 + 
           g3 a p3 + (g4 a p4/\[Tau]4))) zbar4*h4*gamma4));
Print["0=", eq4];

set = a -> # & /@ Range[0, 3, 0.1];

f[x_] := Module[{v}, 
  v = Table[{\[Tau]4, \[Tau]3, \[Tau]2, \[Tau]1} /. 
     NSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, 
        eq4 == 0 && \[Tau]1 > 0 && \[Tau]2 > 0 && \[Tau]3 > 
          0 && \[Tau]4 > 0} /. 
       x[[i]], {\[Tau]1, \[Tau]2, \[Tau]3, \[Tau]4}], {i, 1, 
     Length[x], 1}]; v = Flatten[v, 1];
  mR = Labeled[
    ListLinePlot[v, GridLines -> {None, {1}}, 
     GridLinesStyle -> 
      Directive[
       AbsoluteThickness[3/2] ColorData[97, 
          2] Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], 
     PlotLabel -> Style["MTR- Rawlsian", FontSize -> 18], 
     PlotRange -> {0, 1.05}, PlotLegends -> Values@x, 
     PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, 
     Ticks -> {{{1, zbar4}, {2, zbar3}, {3, zbar2}, {4, zbar1}}, {0.2,
         0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}, 
     TicksStyle -> {Directive[Red, 12], Directive[Red, 8]}, 
     ImageSize -> {800, 300}], "Income Brackets"]]

f[set]
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to replace the parameters with numbers in your equations *before* you solve them numerically. Closest to your current approach is just moving where you apply your replacement rule to inside `NSolve`:

```
  v = Table[{τ4, τ3, τ2, τ1} /. 
     NSolve[{eq1 == 0, eq2 == 0, eq3 == 0, 
        eq4 == 0 && τ1 > 0 && τ2 > 0 && τ3 > 
          0 && τ4 > 0} /. 
       x[[i]], {τ1, τ2, τ3, τ4}], {i, 1, 
     Length[x], 1}];
```

Regarding your labels question. To suppress Legend labels you can set them to `None`.  Placement of `PlotLegends` is controlled with `Placed` so perhaps something like:

```
PlotLegends -> 
 Placed[Flatten[{x[[1, 2]], ConstantArray[None, Length[x] - 2], 
    x[[-1, 2]]}], Left]
```

**Update**: Specifically for `PlotLabels`: `PlotLabels` will actually print `None` if given as an argument, so instead you can give it empty strings for labels you don't want. Specifically to only visibly label first and sixth:

```
PlotLabels -> 
 Placed[Flatten[{x[[1]], ConstantArray["", Length[x] - 3], x[[-2]], 
    ""}], Left]
```

**Update${}^2$**:  For Version 10, can hack something together with `Text` Graphics directives.  i.e.

```
Show[ListLinePlot[v, GridLines -> {None, {1}}, 
  GridLinesStyle -> 
   Directive[
    AbsoluteThickness[3/2] ColorData[97, 
       2] Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}], 
  PlotLabel -> Style["MTR- Rawlsian", FontSize -> 18], 
  PlotRange -> Automatic, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 10}, 
  Ticks -> {{{1, zbar4}, {2, zbar3}, {3, zbar2}, {4, zbar1}}, {0.2, 
     0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1}}, 
  TicksStyle -> {Directive[Red, 12], Directive[Red, 8]}, 
  Joined -> True],
 Graphics[{Text[x[[1]], {.75, v[[1, 1]]} + {0, .005}], 
           Text[x[[6]], {.75, v[[6, 1]]} + {0, .005}]}]]
```

yields:

[image: listplotTextHack]

Comment: Best bet is just Text graphics directives by hand exactly where you want them, but I'll add the most "automatic" PlotLabels which is "" instead of None.

Comment: Thanks @John! Just PlotLabels stays red when I add it beside the other options of ListLinePlot!

Comment: It's a valid option: `Position[Options[ListLinePlot], PlotLabels]` has it as the 46th option in Version 11.1.

Comment: Oh! Mine is Version 10, and it's not in the options!

Comment: Updated to give example of how you can use text directives even in V10.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @John!